# Can you jump over a campfire with only 1 jump and take no damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to jump over a campfire with only 1 jump (with sprinting) (so no repeated jumps to get extra momentum) and take no damage from the fire? I've done this before, but they all required 1 or 2 starting jumps (to gain momentum) to avoid the fire. Is it possible to achieve this without any starting jumps?

Comment: You can gain enough momentum with jumps that some of it carries through to the next jump? Are you sure that it was different from just sprinting a bit before? I have definitely done this (e.g. 1½m high jump), but only with momentum from elytra.

Comment: Yes (to the first Q). Er I'm not sure, I seem to have a higher success rate with jumping beforehand to get more momentum than just sprinting up and jumping @FabianRöling

Answer (score 2):

Ok apparently after 10+ mins of trial and error apparently it is possible. No commands or anything special needed. All you have to get >2 blocks of sprint and then jump the moment you reach the block in front of the campfire (or in other words reach the end of the block that is 2 block away).